# Limit of $a_{n}^{2}$ when the sequence is recursive

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The problem states:

Given the sequence:

$$a_0 \in \left(0,1\right)$$
$$a_{n+1}= 1 - \sqrt {1-a_{n}^{2}}$$

**First part.**

Check whether it converges, and if so find its limit.

**Second part.**

Find:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {a_{n}^{2}}{a_{n+1}}$$

The first part is clear to me, and I've done it. I've proven that the sequence is bounded (0 from below and 1 from above), and also that it is monotone decreasing, so the sequence converges to 0.

The second part is what confuses me. If the sequence is given recursively, how do I know what $a_n$ even is? Furthermore, how do I put it in a limit that I'm supposed to evaluate?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Do not use embedded images please. Instead, please write your question with [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (in both the title and in the body of the question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to point out that the fact that $a_n$ is bounded below by $0$ and decreasing only implies that it converges and that its limit $L$ satisfies $L\geqslant 0$.
In fact, *in this case* $L$ must be $0$, but this must be deduced, for instance via

\begin{align}
L = 1 - \sqrt{1-L^2}
&\implies (L-1) = -\sqrt{1-L^2}
\\
&\implies (L-1)^2 = 1-L^2
\\
&\implies 2L^2-2L = 0
\\&\implies L(L-1) = 0 \implies L=0 \text{ or } L=1.
\end{align}

---

As for the second part, consider that your recurrence relation implies

\begin{align}
&(a_{n+1}-1) = -\sqrt{1-a_n^2}
\\
\implies &(a_{n+1}-1)^2 = 1-a_n^2
\\
\implies &a_n^2 = 1 - (a_{n+1}^2-2a_{n+1}+1) = 2a_{n+1} - a_{n+1}^2.
\end{align}

It follows that

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n^2}{a_{n+1}}
&=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2a_{n+1} - a_{n+1}^2}{a_{n+1}}
\\&=
\lim_{n\to\infty} 2 - a_{n+1} = 2,
\end{align}

where the last step follows from your previous calculation.

Comment: @OscarLanzi If $a_n \in A$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \in \overline{A}$ $($the closure of $A)$. In our case, $A = (0,1)$, so $L \in [0,1]$, ie, $0\leqslant L \leqslant 1$.

Comment: Got my signs mixed up, but partly because I am led down the garden path.  If $L\ge 0$ and the choices are $0$ and $1$, we miss a step that eliminates the latter.  Put $0\le L \le a_1$ instead of just $L\ge 0$ and things go smoothly.

Comment: If $a_n \in (0,1)$ for all $n$, $(a_n)$ is decreasing and $L=0$ or $1$, then the choice is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Since $a_n \to 0$ we have

$$\frac{a_n^2}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{a_n^2}{1-\sqrt{1-a_n^2}}=\frac{a_n^2}{1-\sqrt{1-a_n^2}}\,\frac{1+\sqrt{1-a_n^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-a_n^2}}=$$$$=\frac{a_n^2\left(1+\sqrt{1-a_n^2}\right)}{1-1+a_n^2}=1+\sqrt{1-a_n^2}\to 2$$

Comment: I would argue that the $O$-notation is not reasonable for a task obviously given to someone who recently started doing actual math. While what you said is true, it doesn't really help the understanding imho.

Comment: @Sellerie I'm using little-o notation. If the OP is not aware about that we can avoid that using the limit $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{x} \to \frac 12$.

Comment: @Sellerie I've simplified all the derivation without little-o notation.